# identify a particular page with php

Tags: slideshow

I have to insert some sliders in some particular pages of wordpress site.

https://www.mousampictures.com/department/wedding/

when I have added the slider code, its appearing all at a time.

How can if do something like:

```
if (page is wedding){
echo wedding slider
}
if (page is portrait){
echo portrait slider
}
```

the page admin side url is:

> https://www.mousampictures.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=department&tag_ID=38&post_type=portfolio

I tried something like below:

```
<div class="layout-full">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <!-- wedding --THIS DOSN'T WORK :( -->      
            <?php 
                $title = single_cat_title();
                if ( $title == "Wedding")  {
                    echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1710"]');
                }
            ?>

            <!--portrait -->
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1718"]'); ?> 

            <!--travel -->
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="1714"]'); ?>

        </div>
```

but the if condition doesn't work, Instead 'wedding' is printed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to display your slide in specific pages, so you need to control it using if condition.

***debug the code before use,***

1. Only on front page / home page

   is_front_page(); // Use this function

   More reading .  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/
   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/
2. Get Current page name
      $pagename = get_query_var('pagename');

More details , stack overflow answer .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837006/how-to-get-the-current-page-name-in-wordpress

3. Using Advance custom fields , ACF is a free plugin but I think repeater field is paid. anyway it have nice control customfilds.

   **Follow this resources** 
     https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
     https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: the page url is as: https://www.mousampictures.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=department&tag_ID=38&post_type=portfolio

Comment: You posted a admin url,without credentials I cant check, anyway try my example. you can get an idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
     $post_type = get_post_type();
    //var_dump($post_type);
    if($post_type=='wedding'){
      //echo wedding slider
    }
    else if($post_type=='portrait'){
     //echo portrait slider
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am not sure if 'wedding' and 'portrait' are actually post types--

Comment: if you are trying to add the slider in pages use page id or check with `is_page()` with page slug or id

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: you can use following condition to check current page with page id so if condition satisfy echo slider ` if (is_page('346') ): //echo
  endif;`

Comment: @ShameemAliP.K I tried that, but its not a page.  is_tax('department') is true, but I am having hardtime filtering out more.

Comment: `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wedding") !== false){
// weddingfound
}` just use snippet i konw not a proper way but time beeing can use.